# How can I calculate my array entry's entrynumber

Tags: c++, arrays, math, sfml

I have a `std::vector<sf::Texture>` which I initialize like this:

```
texture.loadFromFile(assets/texture/faceShadow.png);
textures.push_back(texture);
```

My folders will always be like this:

```
assets/texture/faceShadow.png

//texture: 1, 2, ...
//faceShadow: 1 to 9
```

Here, a sample of what I currently have with a `std::cout` display:

```
assets/1/1.png - (entry n°0)
assets/1/2.png - (entry n°1)
assets/1/3.png - (entry n°2)
assets/1/4.png - (entry n°3)
assets/1/5.png - (entry n°4)
assets/1/6.png - (entry n°5)
assets/1/7.png - (entry n°6)
assets/1/8.png - (entry n°7)
assets/1/9.png - (entry n°8)
assets/2/1.png - (entry n°9)
assets/2/2.png - (entry n°10)
assets/2/3.png - (entry n°11)
assets/2/4.png - (entry n°12)
assets/2/5.png - (entry n°13)
assets/2/6.png - (entry n°14)
assets/2/7.png - (entry n°15)
assets/2/8.png - (entry n°16)
assets/2/9.png - (entry n°17)
```

I have the texture and faceShadow number, **I'm trying to get the entryNumber.**

```
textures[entryNumber];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use modular arithmetic:

```
std::string relativePathToAsset(unsigned entry)
{
    if(entry > 17)
    {
        // handle invalid input (if you like)
    }

    return std::to_string(entry / 9 + 1) + "/" + std::to_string(entry % 9 + 1) + ".png";
}
```

But I believe there's also a way to create multiple textures with different offsets from one image. That seems to be more reasonable in case you're doing animation.

**Edit:**

In the code below:

```
return std::to_string(entry / 9 + 1) + "/" + std::to_string(entry % 9 + 1) + ".png";
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                 formula for texture                  formula for faceShadow
```

You can use like this:

```
int texture    = entry / 9 + 1;
int faceShadow = entry % 9 + 1;
```

**Final edit:**

You actually need an inverse formula to the one I was suggesting:

```
textures[(texture - 1) * 9 + (faceShadow - 1)];
```

Comment: Have you seen how Minecraft stores block textures? - In one file.

Comment: LogicStuff -> Yeah, but they use 3D, i'm in 2D here, i only simulate 3D witht the `sf::VertexArray`. I do this to create a 'shadow system'.

(this is weird, i can't quote your name with @)

But your function give me the path of my texture, i want the entry number.
**EDIT: Oh ! My bad, i didn't said it in my question. Sorry.**

Comment: Hold on, I'll edit the answer. But edit the question of course.

Comment: I edited it. I didn't even wrote the question ha ha, what a mistake.

Comment: Thanks you a lot. When i tried to inverse your previous formula by myself i did something like : `entry = texture * 9 + 1` XD I'm so bad at math... ha ha ha
Your answer is working, thanks again.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm not good at math either, I happen to know these maybe the same way you do now.

Comment: Oh no, i don't understand how you did reversed the formula. I mean, i can't see the link between all those numbers, that's about this i tought you were good at this. I, i just see numbers ha ha ha ... ; _ ;

Comment: Try to substitute `texture` and `faceShadow` in order from `{1,1}` to `{2,9}`, maybe you'll get it then. I don't know how to explain this. There's [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/212808/treating-a-1d-data-structure-as-2d-grid) question however, you can look at that.

Comment: Thanks for links and explanations, i'll try to figure it out, let's math !